# Rails Serializer Return Previous Data If Statement Exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some problems on rails api serializer. There is a if statement for update object, and when I update the object, it returns previous data. But If I remove the if statement then it returns updated version of object.

```
   if @store.schedule_relations.present?
    params[:schedule_params].each do |schedule_param|
       @store.btc_box_merchant_lku_schedule_relations.find_by(day: schedule_param[:day]).update_attributes!(is_open: schedule_param[:is_open], opening_time: schedule_param[:opening_time], closing_time: schedule_param[:closing_time])
    end
  end
```

Store Model looks like this:

```
has_many: :schedules
```

Schedule Model looks like this:

```
belongs_to: :store
```

If I remove if statement, it does work without to reload method.
I can solve with reload, I'm wondering why it behaves like this. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When calling a relation like `@store.schedule_relations` in Ruby on Rails then the result of that query is cached until the end of the current request. Therefore when you change the underlying data then those changes will not show up in subsequent calls of `@store.schedule_relations`.

To clear the cache and force a reload of the associated record with the updated data your need to call

```
@store.schedule_relations.reload
```

See [`ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy#reload`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.3.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-reload).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but if I don't use if @store.schedule_relations.present? it does work without reload. I don't get it.

Comment: Because without the `@store.schedule_relations.present?` the `@store.schedule_relations` cache doesn't get populated and therefore in the serializer it calls that relation for the first time.